# How can i reference variable in lambda to AWS-RunShellScript command

Tags: python, shell, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-ssm

I am trying to pass a variable `account_id` to shell script inside a lambda function, this lambda will run that script on instances for that account

```
import sys
import logging
import datetime
import boto3
import botocore
import time
import json
from os import getenv

region = 'ap-southeast-2'
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name=region)
account_id = 123454

def handler(event, context):
client = boto3.client('ssm')

instance_name_list=\[12345678890,0000000000\]
if instance_name_list:
try:
response = client.send_command(
Targets=\[
{
'Key': 'InstanceIds',
'Values': instance_name_list
},
\],
DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript',
Parameters={
'commands': \[

                      # shell command
                      'echo {account_ID}',
    
                      
                  ]
              }
          )
```

What is the correct way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [`string interpolation`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation).

```
f'echo {account_id}'
```